# obtain transformation matrix from control points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, registration, transformation

We can construct a 'TFORM' structure using control points via the 'cp2tform' function, however I am wondering if we can obtain the explicit  transformation matrix form, not the 'TFORM' structure, so that I can compute the pixel size of the transformed image from the original image, where the pixel size dx does not equal dy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TFORM` is the structure returned, you can access the transformation matrices as:

```
TFORM.tdata.T
```

and

```
TFORM.tdata.Tinv
```

one for the forward transformation, the other its inverse.

You can edit `maketform.m` file in the IPT toolbox and see how they are used internally.

Comment: btw you should also look into the options of the [`imtransform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imtransform.html) function (regarding the size of the transformed image)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are cases in which it will not work. maketform can be called with custom anonymous function, in this case tdata can be anything

Comment: @Andrey: hmm, the question then is are there cases where `cp2tform` calls `maketform` with user-defined transformation?

Comment: Yep, in the `polynomial` mode, for example, it will be c.tdata, not c.tdata.T